# Merge from an upstream remote branch into a local remote branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-fork

We use a fork model in our organization, and I am trying to merge the updates from an upstream branch to my local branch.

This is my git set up.

```
kartik@ ~/sourcecode/myproject (defect-875) $ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com/kartik/myproject.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com/kartik/myproject.git (push)
upstream    git@github.com:MyOrg/myproject.git (fetch)
upstream    git@github.com:MyOrg/myproject.git (push)
```

The upstream has two branches

1. master
2. devel

I need to sync my local branch with `devel` branch upstream.

This is what I have tried

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/defect-875
```

where defect-875 is my local branch.

I always get this error message

> merge: upstream/defect-875 - not something we can merge

I also tried this

```
kartik@ ~/sourcecode/myproject (defect-875) $ git merge upstream/devel -m "Merging from seo redirect."
 merge: upstream/devel - not something we can merge
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: So what *is* `upstream/defect-875`?

Comment: There is no upstream branch with that name. "defect-875" is a local git branch. I have pushed anything yet.

Comment: OK, that certainly explains why Git cannot merge it. :-) Basically, you'd like it to exist once you are all done, though?

Comment: @torek So I want to sync all the changes from devel to my local branch. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

[eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52302098/1256452) is the right one here, I think, but it sounds like you should learn a few Git tricks.

The first thing to know about Git is that it's mostly about *commits*.  Branches—or really, branch *names* (see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))—exist in Git so that Git, and we, can find the commits.

You probably already know that a commit is, in effect, a snapshot of a source tree.  (If you didn't, well, now you do!)  But it has a little bit more as well.  First, every commit has a unique "true name" in the form of its hash ID.  A branch name is a way to express the true name of some commit—the hash ID—and `git rev-parse` will show you the actual hash ID:

```
$ git rev-parse master
c05048d43925ab8edcb36663752c2b4541911231
```

These big ugly IDs seem random, but are actually completely determined by the contents of the commit itself.  These contents are pretty short—here's the above commit, with `@<address>` munged a bit to cut down on spam:

```
$ git cat-file -p c05048d43925ab8edcb36663752c2b4541911231 | sed 's/@/ /'
tree a446a29ef7ca90d9c64825fb00a0f1e1a099ca18
parent e9983f8965c0875cc6727e9644c84ff1dfc99372
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1536096807 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1536096807 -0700

Git 2.19-rc2

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

The *tree* line above is how the commit saves the source snapshot (by using another Git internal object).  The *author* and *committer* lines tell us who made the commit and when—1536096807 means `Tue Sep 4 14:33:27 2018`.  The *parent* line gives the big ugly hash ID of the commit that comes *before* this commit.

We say that each of these things that has a hash ID in it *points to* the object.  For much more on this, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/), but for this answer, let me just draw it out like this:

```
...  <-c05048d43925ab8edcb36663752c2b4541911231   <--master
```

The *name* `master` *points to* this commit, which points to the earlier commit `e9983f8965c0875cc6727e9644c84ff1dfc99372`.  That earlier commit points to a still-earlier commit, and so on.

#### All of these names and objects are local to your own repository

You have all of these branch names, like `master` and `defect-875`, in your own repository.  They do not depend on anything outside your own Git.  They point to commits that you have locally as well, and these commits—including their snapshots and their parent commits and those commit's snapshots, all the way back in history—do not depend on anything outside your own Git either.

But you do *get* some commits from some other Git(s).  You do this by having your Git call up those Gits, using the Internet.  Their Git repository has *their* commits with *their* branch names.  The commits all have unique hash IDs, but if they have a commit that has the *same* hash ID—the same true name—as some commit that *you* have, then they and you by definition have the *same commit*.

#### `git fetch` gets the commits they have that you don't

Their *branch names* do not have to match, but the commit hash IDs *do* have to match.  Either they match, and you have the commit, or they have a commit that you don't.  So your Git calls up their Git and says: *What names do you have and what are their commit hash IDs?*  Their Git gives your Git this list, and your Git says to itself: *ah, I have this one* or *hm, I don't have that one.*  Your Git then gives their Git a list of commits that they have, that your Git *wants*, and their Git packages up these commits—including their snapshots—and sends them over.

At the end of this process, you have all of your commits (including any commits you already had that they have) *plus* all of their commits.  Note that they send you not just the tip-most commits—the ones to which the branch names point directly—but also the parent commit, the parent's parent, and so on, as needed so that you get commits that *connect back to* your own commits.

#### `git fetch` also gets their branch names; now what?

You also have their branch names.  But these are *their* branch names, so now your Git *renames* these things.  If your Git called up their Git using `git fetch upstream`, your Git *renames* their `master`, calling it `upstream/master`, and renames their `devel`, calling it `upstream/devel`.

We can draw the commits like this, using round `o`s to stand in for the actual hash IDs, although I have to now start guessing how *many* commits they have that you don't.  Before you run `git fetch upstream`, you have something like this:

```
... <-o <-o <-o   <-- master
               \
                o   <-- defect-875
```

where your `defect-875` commit points back to the tip of your `master` branch, which points back to some earlier commit, and so on.  Once you run `git fetch upstream`, though, you have something more like this:

```
                     o--o   <-- upstream/devel
                    /
             o--o--o   <-- upstream/master
            /
...--o--o--o   <-- master
            \
             o   <-- defect-875
```

(it's getting too hard to draw in the arrows so I've replaced most of them with lines—just remember that they always point backwards).

#### Now you can merge

When you run `git merge`, you must tell your Git *which commit to merge with*.  You usually do this by giving it a branch name, or a remote-tracking name like `upstream/devel`.  This name resolves to a commit hash ID—you can run `git rev-parse` to see how that works, just as I showed above.  It works *because* `git fetch` obtained their `devel` and renamed it to be your own `upstream/devel`.  If you have not yet run `git fetch upstream`, you must do that first, so that your Git has their commits and has renamed their `devel` to become your `upstream/devel`.

#### Merging

At this point, *all the work takes place in your own repository.*  Let's say my drawings have been accurate; but let's simplify this to just the interesting names, and attach the word `HEAD` to the one you have checked out right now.  I'll also put in one-letter names for three interesting commits:

```
                     o--R   <-- upstream/devel
                    /
             o--o--o
            /
...--o--o--B
            \
             L   <-- defect-875 (HEAD)
```

Running `git merge upstream/devel` will find your current or `HEAD` commit `L` (for Left or Local or `--ours`); your commit labeled `upstream/devel`, which is commit `R` (for Right or Remote or `--theirs`); and use `L` and `R` to work back to the common starting point, which is commit `B` (for Base).

Your Git will then, in effect, run two `git diff` commands, to see what you changed—what's different in `B` vs `L`—and to see what they changed, i.e., what's different in `B` vs `R`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-B> <hash-of-L>   # what we did
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-B> <hash-of-R>   # what they did
```

Git now combines—*merges*—these two sets of changes.  If they combine easily, Git applies the combined changes to the snapshot associated with commit `B`, and makes a new commit out of the result.  This is a *merge commit*, a special kind of commit.  What makes it special is simply that it has two parents instead of one: it lists your own commit `L` first, as its first parent, and then their commit `R` as its second parent.

It might help a little if we flip the drawing upside down, so I will do that here.  The result looks like this:

```
             L----------------M   <-- defect-875 (HEAD)
            /                /
...--o--o--B                /
            \              /
             o--o--o      /
                    \    /
                     o--R   <-- upstream/devel
```

This new commit `M` exists on your own `defect-875` branch.

#### Sending the new commits to `upstream`

You can now, if you are authorized anyway, use `git push` to *create* a `defect-875` branch on the Git repository your Git refers-to as `upstream`, using:

```
git push upstream defect-875
```

This has your Git call up their Git, offer *to them* a list of commits that *you* have that *they* don't—which in this case is exactly the two commits `L` and `M`—and then suggest to their Git that they create a branch named `defect-875`, using commit `M` as its tip commit.

If they obey all these requests and suggestions, your Git will remember that they did that, and add to your own set of names, the name `upstream/defect-875`:

```
             L----------------M   <-- defect-875 (HEAD), upstream/defect-875
            /                /
...--o--o--B                /
            \              /
             o--o--o      /
                    \    /
                     o--R   <-- upstream/devel
```

Your own branch `defect-875` is not changed in any way: your name `defect-875` still identifies your commit `M` (by its actual hash ID, whatever that is).  You have merely given their Git these two commits and had their Git set *their* name `defect-875` to match yours.

If you like, you can now set the *upstream* for your own branch `defect-875` to the name `upstream/defect-875`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/defect-875 defect-875
```

If you want to do both when you run `git push`, you can do all of them at once by adding the `-u` flag to your `git push`:

```
git push -u upstream defect-875
```

but that's just a convenience optimization.

Comment: You have a template with that content that you use every once in a while, right? :-D

Comment: No I don't have a template.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should say `git merge upstream/devel -m "Merging from devel"` (having checked out defect-875, just so that we are on the same page).

Comment: My local branch is "defect-875". It does not track any branch in my fork.`devel` is the branch in the upstream repo.

Comment: I did not work. This is the error trace.

kartik@ ~/sourcecode/myproject (defect-875) $ git merge upstream/devel -m "Merging from seo redirect."
merge: upstream/devel - not something we can merge

Comment: Then you probably have not run `git fetch upstream` first. (That, or the remote named `upstream` is not configured correctly, which is much less likely.)

Comment: You are the one that said that upstream remote had those 2 branches. Adjust the formula to the right remote and branch and it should work.